# View internet usage of computers in my network

Tags: network-monitoring, application

What software/application do I need to monitor internet usage of computers in my network
to see sites they are browsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need some form of intelligence in your gateway. You can have monitoring solutions be in-line with traffic or some form of side-band monitoring. I suggest starting with researching [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) as your gateway device and then looking at its many plugins to enable more thorough internet monitoring.

Comment: will i see the sites they are browsing?

Comment: @rjmcb Yes. Research it.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the appliance approach.

If the budget allows, the [Barracuda Web Filter](http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/web-filter-overview.php) is a good solution to monitor and manage internet activity. It has comprehensive reporting, granular configurations and is easy for non-technical users (policy-makers) to manage.